# How to implement `stopping_criteria` parameter in transformers library?

Tags: python, generator, documentation, huggingface-transformers

I am using the python huggingface `transformers` library for a `text-generation` model. I need to know how to implement the `stopping_criteria` parameter in the `generator()` function I am using.

I found the `stopping_criteria` parameter in this documentation:
https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.TextGenerationPipeline

The problem is, I just dont know how to implement it.

My Code:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M')
stl = StoppingCriteria(['###'])
res = generator(prompt, do_sample=True,stopping_criteria = stl)
```

Comment: I was also curious about this. I'd like to be able to provide a particular stopping token (other than the EOS token). Did you work this out?

Comment: How do we resolve "StoppingCriteria() takes no arguments"? It says it's an abstract class; so do we need to define a new class and if so which methods do we override?

Answer (score 2):

These two approaches worked for me. `your_condition` is True when you want to stop.

```py
class CustomStoppingCriteria(StoppingCriteria):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __call__(self, input_ids: torch.LongTensor, score: torch.FloatTensor, **kwargs) -> bool:
        return your_condition

stopping_criteria = StoppingCriteriaList([CustomStoppingCriteria()])
```

OR

```py
def custom_stopping_criteria(input_ids: torch.LongTensor, score: torch.FloatTensor, **kwargs) -> bool:
    return your_condition

stopping_criteria = StoppingCriteriaList([custom_stopping_criteria])
```